# How best to display skewed frequency data?

Tags: data-visualization, skewness, histogram, frequency, ecology

I am counting the number of eggs laid each day by some animals. Most days under my experimental conditions, individuals produce 0 eggs (194/307 observations). I do not want to leave these 0 days out of my analysis because accepted wisdom in the field is that these animals typically produce eggs every day in the wild so it is relevant that this is untrue in my conditions. The range of number of eggs produced on non-zero days is 1-37.

I have considered the following options to display the data but found none satisfying:

1. simple histogram of all counts (the bar for 0 is so big as to obscure data for non-zero days)
2. histogram with a broken y-axis. it seems like it wouldn't be a big deal but I'm using the ggplot2 R package but the fact that ggplot discourages it makes me wonder if it's sort of a "bad look" so rather than switch to plotrix to force the issue I thought I'd investigate other display options.
3. including 2 histograms or density plots, one with 0s and one without
4. table with all counts (the number of bins creates a similar problem to the histogram; it's hard to intuit what it all means because there are so many adjacent but discrete entries of 1-2 observations)
5. tables where clutch size is binned by 5s above either 5 or 10 counts. The table binned above 5 seems promising but I still think a visual presentation that includes every data point would be better.

| clutch size | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 194 |
| 1 | 26 |
| 2 | 17 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5-10 | 28 |
| 11-15 | 14 |
| 16-20 | 2 |
| 21-25 | 2 |
| 26-30 | 6 |
| 31-35 | 1 |
| 36-40 | 1 |

I intend to display separately graphs of clutch size including 0 days and on non-zero days as boxplots (grouped by experimental treatment) but I would like a summary figure that looks at the total counts in my whole experiment, hence the histograms.

Alternative suggestions for displaying these data?

Comment: Could you guide us by providing some hints concerning what aspects of these data you wish to convey and who your intended audience might be?

Comment: This will be the first figure or table in the results section of a manuscript. I mostly want to orient my readers to the data to point out the distribution because the other published papers looking at the phenomenon often leave out 0 days, and/or stop their observations after only 1 or 2 days and conclude that under similar conditions to mine some animals produce eggs daily and other animals never do. I found this to be untrue; if I observe the same animals for 5+ days they almost all eventually produce at least one egg.

Comment: General zoologists/ecologists interested in reproductive biology would be the type of audience